# SnapKit. Replace storyboard constrains

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, snapkit

If I create UIButton instance in code and apply constrains using Snapkit framework - it is working as expected. But when I try apply the same code to @IBOutlet button (defined in storyboard), nothing happen - I see button on the same position / size as it was on storyboard...

Sample code:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

or

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

and constrains are

```
    button.snp_makeConstraints { make in
        make.width.equalTo(150)
        make.height.equalTo(50)
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.snp_centerX)
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.snp_centerY).offset(-40)
    }
```

I have tried to call `button.snp_removeConstraints()` before `snp_makeConstraints()` method without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SnapKit removes only own constraints.For storyboard constraints you need remove view from superview or use this snippet to clear all default constraints

```
view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Small clarifying questions - is it ok to call this in viewDidLoad?

Comment: working in viewDidLoad  shouldn't be problem but if you encounter any problem you may use viewDidLayoutSubviews instead.